# How to fix fuzzy spotify icon in the icon tray?

Tags: 14.04, spotify

I installed a Spotify client today on my recent Ubuntu 14.04 installation and I realized that the icon in the tray is very distorted:

[image]

Is there any way to fix this in Ubuntu 14.04? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

Serious props to **asymptotically** for this one! His solution was amazing:

[image]

Now Spotify actually looks like it belongs on my icon tray. Awesome job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found [this](http://michaeltunnell.com/blog/16-linux/22-ubuntu-ambiance-theme-for-spotify-plus-radiance-icon), and it's actually excellent. [Download](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/spotifylinux/Ubuntu%20Ambiance/1.3.0%20for%20Spotify%200.9.4.183/ubuntu-ambiance-theme-for-0.9.4.183.zip?r=http://michaeltunnell.com/projects/18-linux-spotify-themes/30-ubuntu-ambiance&ts=1397921497&use_mirror=hivelocity), extract, copy `resources.zip` to `/opt/spotify/spotify-client/Data` (overwriting the existing file), and restart Spotify.

UPDATE: Spotify released a new update, and allowing the update rewrites the `resources.zip` file. The theme has considerably changed, so the same zip won't work - however, you just need to copy over `resources.zip`, extract, and in the `_linux` subdirectory, delete all files and copy over `_linux/spotify_icon.ico` from the one that you downloaded, zip it back up and copy the zip file back

Comment: I got an error with this. Apparently the zip compression used by Ubuntu 14.04 is different than the zip compression used by Spotify. I keep getting the `failed to load skin` error when recompressing.

Comment: I have created a shell script to fix the Spotify icon based on this answer. https://github.com/faviouz/fix-spotify-icon

Answer (score 13):

Based on asymptotically's answer I have created a simple [shell script to fix the Spotify icon](https://github.com/faviouz/fix-spotify-icon).

To install the script run:

```
$ sh -c "$(wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/faviouz/fix-spotify-icon/master/install.sh -O -)"
```

To fix the icon run:

```
$ fix-spotify-icon
```

Comment: faviouz: someone just edited your answer anonymously.  If it was you, please log on first and then re-edit...

Comment: @Fabby: It wasn't me. I don't see what or how the edit fixed anything anyway.

Comment: @faviouz: Good, I rejected it anyway and then posted my comment as I'm not smart enough to understand what the &|@"# you said because I don't use spotify...  :P  ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Thank you very much asymptotically.

Regarding the `failed to load skin` error, you don't need to extract Spotify's `resources.zip` file in order to edit it - you can just enter the directory and then copy the new file across:

1. Open nautilus as root (*i.e.*, in a terminal, enter `gksu nautilus` and then enter your password);
2. Navigate to `/opt/spotify/spotify-client/Data/resources.zip/_linux`;
3. Download [ubuntu-ambience-theme-for-0.9.4.183.zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/spotifylinux/files/Ubuntu%20Ambiance/1.3.0%20for%20Spotify%200.9.4.183/ubuntu-ambiance-theme-for-0.9.4.183.zip/download?use_mirror=skylink) and then extract it. Extract `resources.zip` and then enter the `_linux` directory;
4. Replace the `spotify_icon.ico` file in `/opt/spotify/spotify-client/Data/resources.zip/_linux` with the one in `ubuntu-ambience-theme-for-0.9.4.183.zip`;
5. Start Spotify.